# Python. Создание папки в ОС Линукс

Tags: python, linux

Как в питоне создать папку по определенному пути?
Допустим мне надо создать папку с именем '1234' сюда `/home/korobeinikovi/pypro`.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Произвольная вложенность + директория уже может существовать:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path("/home/korobeinikovi/pypro/1234").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```